# MySQL semicolon in update statement is causing syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a MySQL DB (5.7.18) with articles table. Each article has an abstract as an HTML string in `abstract` column. Due to a bug in the HTML editor, many of HTML tags are polluted with annoying style, like this:

```
<h1 style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Wonderful Abstract</h1>
```

In order to fix this I am trying the following query:

```
UPDATE `article` SET `abstract`=REPLACE(`abstract`,' style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"','')
```

Unfortunately, a syntax error is shown:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0))' at line 1

If the semicolon is removed it works fine:

```
UPDATE `article` SET `abstract`=REPLACE(`abstract`,' style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0)"','');
```

But it must be replaced in the string too...

I found a reference [here](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,132124,166891#msg-166891) saying to escape it:

```
UPDATE `article` SET `abstract`=REPLACE(`abstract`,' style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0)\;"','')
```

But the error message is still shown.

Another option described in the same origin is to add a semicolon to the end of the statement:

```
UPDATE `article` SET `abstract`=REPLACE(`abstract`,' style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"','');
```

And the combination of those two:

```
UPDATE `article` SET `abstract`=REPLACE(`abstract`,' style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0)\;"','');
```

The error message is still there.

Comment: I can't seem to [reproduce](http://rextester.com/OOQ84230) this issue locally, at least the text replacement by itself works for me.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour... http://rextester.com/BZAPY91725 Perhaps you're using a SPROC?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. So it's probably something specific to my environment.

Comment: Cant reproduce. semicolon in a string should not cause any problem, still enclose the string in single quotes in insert statement. Try to end your statement with ;$$ 
Delimiter ;. (Not sure if this helps)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it.

It was a field in phpMyAdmin which is set to semicolon(;) by default.

I have changed it to an unused char and the query ran normally.

[image: Delimiter]

Comment: phpMyAdmin? Man... there are some better choices out there :p

Comment: There's no accounting for taste‏‏‏‏... (it rhymes in hebrew: עַל טַעַם וְעַל רֵיחַ אֵין לְהִתְוַכֵּחַ).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and found a workaround:

```
UNHEX( REPLACE( HEX( TEXT_FIELD ), '3B', ''))
```

eliminates the semicolon from `TEXT_FIELD`.

I needed to rip off html tags from a string in a field, without escaping (which does not work in MariaDB) and without changing the `SQLTERMINATOR` (which I could not use in a report query).
The string contained a semicolon ';' so I used `HEX( myString)` to eliminate it first and then the rest of the tags:

```
REPLACE     ( 
    REPLACE     ( 
        REPLACE     (
            UNHEX( REPLACE( HEX( TEXT_FIELD  ), '3B', '' ) )
                    , '<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: left">', '' 
                )
      ,  '</p>', '' )
   , '<br>', '' )
```

Hope this is useful