# trying to replace some strings in the database with &lt;

Tags: mysql

we had some strings in the database which were html tags ( added intentionally ) and now we want to change the <> but when we try to replace the < by "<" it does not work and it is because of the ;.
I tried to escape it but no go..

my command

```
UPDATE ads SET `placement` = REPLACE(`placement`, '<', "&lt\;") WHERE id =1;
```

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: works fine in my side with mysql5.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL semicolon in update statement is causing syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298640/mysql-semicolon-in-update-statement-is-causing-syntax-error)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand correctly but

possible duplicate of [Update a column value, replacing part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

You can try something like below:
if you want to replace < with &lt;

> update ads set placement = REPLACE(placement, '<', '&lt;');

or this if you want to replace < with "<"

> update ad set placement = REPLACE(placement, '<', '\"<\"');

Ampersand is not a special character, more about specail characters
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html

Let's know if you were looking for this or something else.