# #1064 syntax mysql error with &quot; symbol

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove all `"` symbols in `name` column

```
UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, "&quot;", "");
```

When I try to simulate this query I get this syntax error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"&quot)' at line 1

Comment: `UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '"', '');`

Comment: i have a data with `&quot;` text in this column. so i need only `&quot;`, not `"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303704/10321657 i have changed the delimiter and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

It works fine here:

```
CREATE TABLE oc_product_description  (
`name` varchar(50) 
                                   ) ;
INSERT INTO oc_product_description values
('some random text &quot;'),
('some  text &quot;'),
('some  text');


UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '&quot;', '');
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=549e0e574355f8301b575cb05694dd66)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE oc_product_description SET 
name = REPLACE(name, '&quot;', '');
```

Comment: i have a data with `&quot;` text in this column. so i need only `&quot;`, not `"`

Comment: UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '&quot;', '');

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '&quot;', '');
```

I did a similar query in phpmyadmin. In check mode it shows an error, but when finally executed it is fine